# Wildfly fail to respond to some of the requests when there are too many requests

Tags: web-services, wildfly, nio, stress-testing

I am using Wildfly 9.0. I am developing a web program with two main parts.
One is submitting the request the server itself's webservice, and another one is a web service which receive request and work on it with the database.

The whole flow is like
1.user open a webpage rendered from the server and submit some information
2.the information is submitted to the server
3.the server then submit a HTTP request to the web service of the same server
4.the web service handle the request and reply.
5.the resulting information is then rendered to the user

For example, some of the requests are generated like this in the server to the web service...

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/myPathOfRFWS/someWS";
HttpUriRequest httpReq = new HttpPost(url);
httpReq.addHeader("userKey", "someString");
try (DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();) {
    HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpReq);
    return resp;
} catch (Exception e) {
    logException(e);
}
```

The code work perfectly fine under normal situation.
However, when I am performing Stress Test on the server with JMeter (maybe like submitting 60 requests in 60seconds, each with some steps of processing, so probably there may be around 8-10 on-going requests running at the same time in JMeter), I find that there are often a few requests failing to be received on the web service side, and hence no response to the client.
I have checked with the thread dump, and find that the server has submitted the request to web service, but the web service seems doesn't receive the request nor do any action after the action is passed through the filter.
Here are some part of the thread dump.

```
"default task-26" #298 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001a497000 nid=0xd3c runnable [0x000000001fa7d000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
- locked <0x00000000fde172b0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000fde172a0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
- locked <0x00000000fde17040> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
at org.xnio.nio.SelectorUtils.await(SelectorUtils.java:46)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.awaitReadable(NioSocketConduit.java:345)
at org.xnio.conduits.AbstractSourceConduit.awaitReadable(AbstractSourceConduit.java:66)
at io.undertow.conduits.ReadDataStreamSourceConduit.awaitReadable(ReadDataStreamSourceConduit.java:101)
at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.awaitReadable(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:272)
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:151)
at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:77)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.awaitReadable(HttpServerExchange.java:1997)
at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:295)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:170)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:146)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:133)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.writeTo(ProviderHelper.java:124)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider.readFrom(FileProvider.java:88)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider.readFrom(FileProvider.java:34)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:62)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:51)
at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:32)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:150)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at com.mypackage.web.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:54)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x0000000084370a18> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


"default task-23" #295 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001a494800 nid=0x3d8 runnable [0x000000001dfac000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at com.mypackage.WsLib.callUriWs(WsLib.java:241)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x0000000084363dd8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Please advise if there is anything I can do to solve the issue or to check with the issue.

Comment: Found to be because all the threads are used and no more spare thread. I have adjust in standalone.xml and set the task-max-threads of the worker. Then problem is solved. 

<worker name="default" task-max-threads="250"/>

Comment: Solved it for us too - you should make this an answer I suppose.